# Firefox sends many requests?

Tags: firefox, website

There seems to be a Problem with Firefox on Youtube, when i try to watch a video, the site show me a captcher saying the site received many requests from my Network, then I have to fill a captcher to be recognized not as robot. On some days it works, and sometimes not.

I already tried another Browser "Edge", and it works fine there. I tried also to disable the add-ons on firefox and does not work.
But I noticed when I'm logged in with an account(email) on youtube, it works without the captcher.

I tried to use the Network analyzer tool within Firefox, but how to read thru the lines, or should be instead used antoher extern tool ?

Thanks

Comment: YouTube, a Google company, works notoriously bad on Firefox, a direct competitor to Google Chrome... This said, all browsers send mutliple requests to one distant IP, the rationale behind it being that if the first request is ignored by the server due to overload, or packets are lost, you, the end-user, will be served with the page you want to see via the subsequent requests. It makes for a lot of strain on servers, and some shut you out if you abuse the system. You can try to disable the "enable prefetch" options in about:config (leave those who say "disable" alone) and see if it's better.

Comment: Thanks, but which config flag do you mean, I found a couple:   (network.dns.disablePrefetch false) 
(network.dns.disablePrefetchFromHTTPS true) 
(network.predictor.enable-prefetch false) 
(network.predictor.prefetch-force-valid-for 10) 
(network.predictor.prefetch-min-confidence 100) 
(network.predictor.prefetch-rolling-load-count 10) 
(network.prefetch-next)

Comment: network.dns.disablePrefetch.should be on true, since you want to disable it. Ditto network.predictor.enable-prefetch (set to true). What's the value for network.prefetch-next? Should be false.

Comment: The last was true, I changed all the mentioned flags accordinly. Should I restart Firefox ? Seems the Problem persists. Only with the account logged in, it works. Okay I will test it, thank you.